# how to remove dot from string in lua

Tags: lua

I would like remove dot from string.
For example

```
242.701000393 = 242701000393
```

I have tried below code which is working fine in some cases.

```
string.gsub("242.701000393", "%.", "")
```

Same way, I have tried above function for `100999212.707000393` .But it's not working for it.

Am newbie in lua.I would like to just remove .(dot) from string in every cases.

Share your thoughts as i don't know how to achieve it.

As per my logic looks like below

1. split a string by dot and convert into an array
2. concat all array elements

Share it solution if possible.

Thanks in advance.

CODE :

```
local destination_number =100999212.707000393
destination_number = string.gsub(destination_number, "%.", "")
print(destination_number)
```

Output : `100999212707`

Expected output : `100999212707000393`

Comment: What is your output for `100999212.707000393` ? Are you passing `string.gsub()` as argument of `print` function ?

Comment: I just have added my code as well as output.

Comment: number (probably double) is not string. Dot cannot be removed in most programming languages

Comment: You should wrap `100999212.707000393` using quotes `"`, now `type(destination_number)` is number not string.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is the accuracy of the number - floating point rounding, not the function of gsub.

```
local destination_number =100999212.707000393
print(destination_number, type(destination_number) )
destination_number = string.gsub(destination_number, "%.", "")
print(destination_number,type(destination_number))
```

output

```
100999212.707   number
100999212707    string
```

compared to ...

```
local destination_number = "100999212.707000393"
print(destination_number, type(destination_number) )
destination_number = string.gsub(destination_number, "%.", "")
print(destination_number,type(destination_number))
```

output

```
100999212.707000393     string
100999212707000393      string
```

A floating point double has about 15 digits of accuracy, which means the `393` is being lost in the generation of the number.  When converted to a string, it has already gone.

15 digits is quite accurate, and normally good enough for most purposes, but if it is insufficient for you, you will need to consider alternative data representations.

Comment: Thanks man,For good explanation.I can't upvote for now.Will upvote later.